# How can I set url rule for a single controller in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, url-routing

I'm using a url rule in my main.php.But it affects all controllers.How can I set a url rule for a particular controller only ?

```
  'rules' => array(
                // custom rule
                array(
                    'class' => 'application.components.MyUrlRule',
                    'connectionID' => 'db',
                ),
  )
```

MyUrlRule

```
class MyUrlRule extends CBaseUrlRule{

    public $connectionID = 'db';

    public function createUrl($manager,$route,$params,$ampersand)
        {
           //modification & url encryption
        }

    public function parseUrl($manager,$request,$pathInfo,$rawPathInfo)
        {
           //modification & url decryption
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your required URL pattern?

Comment: @Hearaman-హేరామన్  Please check my edit.It's not just simple re-write